# SQLite: calculating from subquery

Tags: sqlite

I have a problem statement: What portion of customers that ordered in October also ordered in September?

To clarify the caluculation should be like this.

Numerator: number of customers who ordered in both Oct and Sep

Denominator: number of customers ordered in October

I have written this query but this gave me 1 as an answer which is wrong.(t1 should be 2 customer_id and t2 should be 10 customer_id, so the answer should be **0.2**)

I can't figure out which part giving me error.

```
select count(t1.customer_id)/count(t2.customer_id)*1.0

from ((SELECT *
       FROM shipping
       WHERE SUBSTR(transaction_date, 1, 2) IN ('09', '10')
       GROUP BY customer_id
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTR(transaction_date, 1, 2)) = 2) AS t1,

      (SELECT *
       FROM shipping
       WHERE SUBSTR(transaction_date, 1, 2) IN ('10')
       GROUP BY customer_id) AS t2) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do a floating-point division, at least one of the two values must already be a floating-point value. The `*1.0` at the end does the conversion after the division; you have to do it earlier:

```
select count(t1.customer_id)*1.0/count(t2.customer_id)
...
```

Comment: Still giving me 1

Answer (score 0):

Too late but since I can't believe that it's not yet answered I will post an answer:

```
SELECT 1.0 *
  ( 
    SELECT COUNT() OVER()
    FROM shipping
    WHERE SUBSTR(transaction_date, 1, 2) IN ('09', '10')
    GROUP BY customer_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTR(transaction_date, 1, 2)) = 2
  ) /
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)
    FROM shipping
    WHERE SUBSTR(transaction_date, 1, 2) = ('10')
  ) percentage
```

The 1st subquery uses `COUNT()` window function to count the number of distinct customers *who ordered in both Oct and Sep* and the 2nd subquery counts the *number of customers ordered in October*.
See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vBFv6hHPycc3aKbcFnmj9L/1).